# Fetching data from redirect url in java is giving 403 error

Tags: java, io

I have to fetch html page of first search result in google. 
For doing that, I'm using google "*I'm Feeling Lucky*", so basically adding **&btnI** to search query url.
So for example - http://www.google.com/search?q=%22movie%22+site:amazon.com&btnI redirects to movies related page on amazon.com

Let that be our searchQuery;

```
searchQuery =  "http://www.google.com/search?q=%22movie%22+site:amazon.com&btnI";
URL url = new URL(searchQuery);
InputStream response = url.openStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response));
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
reader.close();
```

I'm getting 
**Error: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://www.google.com/search?q=%22movie%22+site:amazon.com&btnI** 
Need some help , also if there is a better approach ..do let me know !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Then  `#setFollowRedirects(true)` and set the user-agent for something like Firefox's or IE's.

Like this:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(searchQuery).openConnection();
connection.setFollowRedirects(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2");
connection.connect();
InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
...
```